# How to change the id format of field in a model?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, pgadmin-4

For example I have a field of **customer** `ID`s going from

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
```

However I want to change the format to

```
010101, 010102, 010103, 010104, 010105, ...
```

As it display on my database and templates.

Is there any way of doing that?

I am using PostgreSQL version 12 and pgadmin 4.

I have been using of the below on the query editor

```
SELECT concat('0101', lpad(id, 2, '0')) from public.accounts_customer
```

However receiving the error below

```
ERROR:  function lpad(integer, integer, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT concat('0101', lpad(id, 2, '0')) from public.accounts...
                              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 23
```

Comment: you want just add  the same string prefix 0101 to your id?   what's happen  after the id 99 .??... and you want only see in select or you want update the value in bd?? .. try explain better

Comment: so the format would be for id 99 for example will be 010199 and after that would be 010200. And yes want to update the value in db.

Comment: which  data type are field  customerID ??? is a string or is a  integer?  if the data type is an integer you can  updated  the value with a string (leading 0 are possibile only for string)

Comment: It's integer, plus I have a filter form for the customer ID, so if I'm searching through my template, it needs to be searching the integer value of the ID.

Comment: I have posted  an aswer

Answer (score 0):

You can' t add  leading 0 to an integer and store  in db  you can manage only the selecting result  .. eg

```
 select concat('0101', lpad(yourcol,2,'0'))
 from your_table
```

or try force the cast

```
 select concat('0101', lpad(yourcol,2,'0'::text))
 from your_table
```

Comment: Got error back from the query editor saying "function lpad(integer, integer, unknown) does not exist"

Comment: answer  updated   .. missing a closing  )   .. anyway which db you are using a which version ?? ... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-string.html

Comment: Tried it again, but same error. Using PostgreSQL 12, on pgadmin4

Comment: update your question and add  the exact code you are using ..

Comment: answer  uodated  removed quote

Comment: lpad  is normal string function in postgresql  ..  so check for you condiguration if you ahve the normal string funntion available ..

Comment: answer  updated  with a suggestion for proper casting